Trouble getting current form BLDC generator
I am designing a battery charger using a BLDC motor attached to  stationary bike, I was giving this project hoping to fix the current output because is delivering low amps to the charger even at higher speed, the tests has been as follow:
BLDC: 
170kV
120 max amp
24-36 V
2280 max W
3.5 Nm torque

The plan is to rectify the voltage using  3 phase diode (schottky) then a regulator, a LM25116 to 13.8V, that goes to a solar charger to manage the battery.
When measuring the rpm, i got 7600rpm for a few moments, getting 45.14V , after the regulator I got 13.4V but when connecting to the charger it drops to 12.4V and 2.4A and one can hear how the rpms get low.
I want to be able to deliver at least 10A to the charger.
What should I check in this?
How can i calculate the amps given at certain rpm and voltage without load?
Note: the solar charger can deliver up to 30A to the battery.

Please edit the question to add a schematic of your circuit, with part numbers, and wire gauge used for connections.


one can hear how the rpms get low.

You're pedaling the bike. It's on you to keep the RPMS constant. If you can't, then the RPM goal is set too high :)

The plan is to rectify the voltage using a LM25116 to 13.8V

An LM25116 is a buck converter, not a rectifier. Use a 3-phase Schottky diode bridge to rectify the BLDC output into DC current proportional to torque. There's no need to regulate this voltage.

that goes to a solar charger then to the car battery.

No need for the charger in series with the rectified BLDC output. Just have a voltmeter on the battery. When the voltage reaches about 14V, you can slow down or stop pedaling.
All those extra components between the BLDC and the battery are wasting energy. The less energy conversion, the better. Thus:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The fuses are essential for safety. Absolutely do not bypass them. Any short in the output of the charger or in the rectifier bridge will cause the battery to drive a heavy current into the short and that usually means that something smokes, blows up, and optionally catches fire.
The ammeter tells you the charging current, and is roughly proportional to the biomechanical power the biker puts on the pedals :) The voltmeter tells you when the battery is fully charged. Pedaling a stationary bike is enough effort that I wouldn't go for anything more fancy than that. Trust me, when you see that voltage reach the target value, you will feel like stopping - most of the time :) If you feel like more exercise is needed, get a larger battery capacity or reduce sunlight exposure :)
A BLDC is in principle an AC current source, with current proportional to torque. The compliance voltage range depends on rotational speed, but due to the diode bridge, the torque needed when RPMs are too low is minuscule. Then it's a matter of choosing the BLDC specs to match it to the battery voltage and comfortable RPMs that provide maximum reasonable power for a given pedaler.

I need to regulate the voltage because I can't supply too much voltage to the battery

A car lead acid battery is a pretty damn good voltage regulator. It got so much charge "inertia" that not much changes on a short time scale.
With the simple circuit above, when a dad bod is putting 100W into the BLDC, there will be about 7-8A of charging current to the battery. With three dad bods on the bikes, that's say 20-25A of charge current.
Say we got an 80Ah car battery. 20A of charge current is 1/4C charging.
An car battery has less than 50mΩ internal resistance. When 20A of charge current is being pushed into it, the total voltage is instantenously 50mΩ x 20A = 1V higher than the open circuit voltage.
The internal resistance goes up as the battery discharges. So what will happen, with three dad bods leisurely pedaling, is that a 90% discharged battery voltage will jump to about 13V and stay there for a while, as the battery charges and internal resistance reduces. Eventually the voltage will be rising. After about 3-4 hours, the battery will be fully charged, with voltage at 15V or so. When dads stop pedaling, the voltage will go down to 14V.
So, three people, leisurely pedaling, 3-4 hours to charge an 80Ah battery.
You probably want a bigger battery than that. Say you get four 80Ah batteries in parallel. It will take 3 fit cyclists (not elite) between 6 to 8 hours of hard work at 200W continuous power to fully charge this battery from empty.

Limiting the battery voltage and dumping the excess energy into heat is fairly easy.
First figure out what the maximum 5-min average power input from all cyclists will be. Say it's 200W to stay conservative. So 600W total coming in. The voltage this heat has to be dumped at is about 14.5V, say.
Say we split this into four heaters. That's 150W per heater.
Since \$P=V^2/R\$, then \$R=V^2/P=14.5^2/150=1.4\,\Omega\$.
So, we need four 200W rated resistors between 1-1.4&ohm, and something to control them.
The following circuit will need a 0.1C/W heat sinking for the resistors, and some for the mosfets too. The mosfets would be OK on a 150W TDP CPU cooler I think.

simulate this circuit
As the voltage approaches 14.5V, TL431 starts to draw >1mA of current. That current is mirrored by Q1-Q2 and develops a voltage across R3-R6.  As the current increases, the consecutive mosfets turn on. That's so that only one mosfet out of 4 will be dissipating more heat due to partial conduction, the ones on the left will be fully turned on and dissipate about 5W each, and the ones on the right will be off.
Due to safe operating area limitations, the mosfets should be doubled up - M12 is two mosfets in parallel, etc.

The voltmeter is for the weak! Real men use dump load in the water heater. You stop when the water is hot enough for a shower.

Oh my bad, will correct that, yes, i am using a 3-phase Shottcky and then a regulator.
The idea is to replace the solar panel with the power of one or more bikes, the solar charger controller will simply manage the battery charge, when full, will stop, but one can still using the bike.
I need to regulate the voltage because I can't supply too much voltage to the battery, is not safe, also to the charge controller.

@fraxinus already tried to use heat resistance, but that's a linear resistance, connecting to a charger induces inductive or capacitive resistance, maybe putting a filter will be neccesary

I need to regulate the voltage because I can't supply too much voltage to the battery Lol, try. You won't be able to. Again, the torque you apply to the pedals is proportional to the current. Batteries when well charged have a fairly low resistance, so it takes a lot of current to raise the voltage to unsafe levels instantaneously. Instead, the current and battery capacity dictate a rate at which the voltage will be raising over time. An average human (not a fitness buff) will be pushing out maybe 7A out of that BLDC into the battery. Once the voltage (state of charge) is high, stop.

A charged car battery has internal resistance around 50mohm.  Adding one amp more into the battery raises the voltage by a measly 50mV (0.05V). You'll need 20 amps, or an elite cyclist peak power output to instantaneously raise the battery voltage by just 1 V. So if the unloaded battery is at 13V and three dad bods bike at the same time, it will raise to 14V, and then keep raising slowly as the battery charges. You really got to try it out before you overcomplicate stuff.

that's a linear resistance, connecting to a charger induces inductive or capacitive resistance I have no idea what you mean. Maybe that charge controller is stupidly designed? Anyway, if you really want to limit the battery voltage, you can add a low-dropout linear pre-regulator using an MJ2955 on a heatsink. Once the battery reaches the regulated voltage, the bikes will lose all resistance.

An average human (not a fitness buff) will be pushing out maybe 7A out of that BLDC into the battery That's what I am trying to accomplish, but I don't know why can't keep the current flow if my regulator it's fine, so that's why I am also asking what kind of BLDC should I get or how to calculate the current at given rpm based on my kV

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica is there a way we can talk via DM?
